# server socket not worked and catch the IO exception

Tags: android, eclipse, sockets

i am trying to do socket client/server, but i have a problem with the server code.
this problem is relating to the creation of server socket it self
it print "changed2" not "changed", i.e. it catch the exception and doesn't create server socket
server code:

```
package com.example.do2do2messanger;

import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Codes extends Activity {

private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
EditText sended;
TextView mirrored,chatwindow;
Button copied;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gui);

    // text view of the messages
    mirrored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mirror_id);

    try
    {
        server = new ServerSocket(6789,100);
        mirrored.setText("changed");            
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        mirrored.setText("changed2");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Note: Main fest includes this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
```

Comment: note: Mainfest include this:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>

Comment: show what printed to logcat by e.printStackTrace();

Comment: it's too large (logcat)

Comment: i tried but it gives error (syntax error)

Comment: i fix it, try again. change "e.printStackTrace();" to "throw new RuntimeException(e);" and post exception message from logcat here

Comment: Is "6789" your IP????

Comment: `mirrored.setText("changed2");`. Change that to 'mirrored.setText("IOException: " + e.getMessage());` to see the reason.